# Why is my R.java file not generating the display id or the button1 id from my XML file?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, r.java-file

I have Googled and read several Stack Overflow answers and I am pretty sure the problem is with my layout file here. I also cleaned my project so my R.java file was deleted, but I think after I find the error it will be auto-generated.

Here is my XML code.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20sp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/update"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/guess"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="6sp"
        android:paddingTop="6sp"
        android:text="@string/default"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="evaluate"
        android:text="@string/btn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the java lines where there is an error shown, in case there's a problem here:

```
Button button = (Button) view;
TextView log = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.display));
EditText field = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.guess));
```

Update: Here is my evaluate method from the MainActivity.java file

```
public void evaluate(View view)
{
    Button button = (Button) view;
    TextView log = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.display));
    EditText field = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.guess));

    if(button.getText().toString().charAt(0) == 'S')
    {
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(field.getText().toString());
        if(guess == num)
        {
            log.setText("Congratulations! You guessed it in " + guessCount + "moves");
            button.setText("New game");
        }
        else
        {
            guessCount++;
            if(guess < num)
                log.setText("Try again. Too low");
            else
                log.setText("Try again. Too high");
        }
    }
    else
        refresh(button, log);
}
```

Comment: Did you imported the `R` class from your project and **not** `android.R`? Did you check the `Problems` view in `Eclipse`?

Comment: also post log when u are getting error

Comment: What is `view` in the line `Button button = (Button) view;`?

Comment: @Luksprog all my errors are shown to come from MainActivity.java for R not being generated

Comment: @Squonk that is what is passed in from the registered onClick method

Comment: @user1796994 : OK, post the code for your `evaluate` method.

Answer (score 2):

`R.java` is deleted whenever there exists any compile error in `res` folder or in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Assuming you have no compile errors(except the files that should be referencing fields in R.java), my first call is to look at `evaluate` method to see if it is in the current invoking `Activity` as follows:

**Java Code:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    TextView log;
    EditText field;
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button = (Button) new Button(this);
        log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guess);
        ...
        ...
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                evaluate(v);
            }
        });
    }
    ...
    ...
    // **evaluate** is visible(public) and 
    // within the same activity where the **button** is
    public void evaluate(View v) { 
        ...
        ...

    }
}
```

`

Comment: wait can you use 'findViewById()' in the evaluate method?

Answer (score 0):

doesn't eclipse show you any error in the foler of res?

in the line of: **android:onClick="evaluate"**, I haven't seen such value before, is it correct?

Comment: You can register a method to handle a click for that `Button` using the `onClick` attribute, so it's correct.

Comment: @VinsonCai the only error I get is from strings.xml something completely different

Comment: An error in strings.xml will prevent it from generating R.java, so it's probably *not* irrelevant.